# Linq To Entities: "Sequence contains no elements" with Count()

Tags: entity-framework

In our appliction we have a piece of code with some Linq-queries (EF) that sometimes throws an exception.

This has only happened to the end user, and we are not able to reproduce it so far.

From the logfile we got the following stacktrace for the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
>      at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>      at MT3.uctXGrid.LoadLayout(String strUniqueID, Boolean rethrowException, List`1 visibleColumns)

In the method `LoadLayout` there are only 2 instances of `Count()`, and they are just operating on standard `IQueryable`s which interrogate an entity type based on one integer field and select all fields (no aggregations or anything).

ex:

```
from p in cxt.genData where datId = ID
```

In the stacktrace, it seems like internally `.Single()` is being used which could throw an exception if there are no records.

But why is it using single if we are just calling `.Count()` ?

How can a query like

```
(from p in cxt.genData where datId = ID).Count()
```

throw a "sequence contains no elements" exception?

We have had other strange problems with queries as well, I'm starting to wonder if there are any issues with our version of EF maybe.

We are still on 4.0 at the moment. (Standard version which came with VS2010).

Has anyone got an idea what could be going on here?

Update:
Here are the Linq-to-Entities queries we actually use

```
Dim qryLastLayout = From t In oContext.genGridLayouts Where t.layID = intCurrentLayoutID  
If Not IsNothing(qryLastLayout) AndAlso qryLastLayout.Count <> 0 Then

Dim qryPrintSettings = From p In oContext.genPrintSettings Where p.prtDefault = True  
If Not IsNothing(qryPrintSettings) AndAlso qryPrintSettings.Count <> 0 Then
```

Comment: how are you using the Count() result (number of items or just to check if an item exists)?

Comment: We are just checking if Count() != 0, so we know if there is at least one record. We used to check with FirstOrDefault but changed that a while back because we were getting other weird exceptions.

Comment: Consider using `.Any()` if you want to know if there is any record, is more efficient than `.Count()`

Comment: Also, it seems you have a type in your code: `(from p in cxt.genData where datId = ID).Count()`. Shouldn't it be `where datId == ID` (double equals sign)?

Comment: That's not a typo, our code is in visual basic which only uses a single = for comparison

Comment: is the id comparison comparing with the only `Key` column?

Comment: See the end of my post for an update with the queries used. The first one queries on the primary key field, the second one queries on a boolean field.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the .Any() method?

```
if(cxt.genData.Any(x => x.datId == ID))
{
     // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be aware of wrt Linq to Entities is that the semantics of `Count()` are not those of .NET but those of the underlying datasource (somewhat undermining the whole language-integration aspect, but oh well...).  I don't think this can cause issues like yours, but you never know.

MSDN link with more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738551.aspx#sectionSection5